# A word to refer to a spoiled person who just use fashion clothing or brands

Tags: word-request

In Portuguese we have the slang 'coxinha' to refer to a person who is spoiled and live by using fashion clothing and products of famous brands.

Is there a word in english for that kind of people?

Comment: Fashion victim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that one possible word for this is "fashionista".

The definition from [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fashionista) seems to fit well:

> fashionista in British English (ˌfæʃəˈniːstə  ) NOUN informal a person
> who follows trends in the fashion industry obsessively and strives
> continually to adopt the latest fashions

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!! Thanks.

Comment: Remember not to use screenshots or snapshots henceforth. You can copy and paste the meaning here, in bold letters for emphasis that is taken from somewhere.